# Teapot Riddle: all of my teapots can be 'strong'

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

If you don't know what a teapot riddle is read closely:
The 'teapot' is one word I'm currently searching for.
You have to guess it.
It's always the same word but has different meanings.

First clue:

> All of my teapots can be 'strong'
>   My first teapot grows strong.
>   My second teapot is designed to be strong.
>   My third teapot is strong if made right.

Second clue:

> My first teapot is really cute, when its young .
>   My second teapot isnt designed to be cute, but it can be.
>   My third teapot is technically not cute.

Third clue:

> My first teapot is mostly wet.
>   My second teapot is after movement wet.
>   My third teapot is technically not wet.

Final clue (makes it reaaally easy):

> My first teapot lives in the water, its like a lion there!
>  My second teapot lives mostly on land, but can be found everywhere!
>  My second teapot loves also the USA
>  My third teapot is a magical tool for imprisoning or hiding

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! For the uninitiated such as myself, what is a teapot riddle? How does it differ from a normal riddle? Thanks!!

Comment: @EL-Guest A teapot riddle to tell form wikipedia is:  "The 'Teapot Game' is a word game described by Mary White's Book of Games, and involves guessing a word which is replaced by "teapot" in various sentences."  The teapot word is always the same word but with a different 'meaning'

Comment: Thanks, @Jannis! I think (there are meta posts about Riley riddles regarding this) that the tags you’ve used are most appropriate for this riddle! I don’t think a teapot tag should be created, because wordplay/word/riddle as you have done already encompasses the spirit of this puzzle! Looks like a great riddle! :)

Comment: @El-Guest okay good to know :) have very much fun thinking about the solution

Comment: Great first riddle! I suggest you un-hide whatever hints are necessary to solve the riddle. I assume probably the first, second and third hint are intended to be the actual clues, whereas the final one serves just as an extra hint.

Comment: well i accidently hid the hints even though you only have to hid the answer. Weeell it wasn't too bad/hard hopefully

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is

> Seal/SEAL/seal

First hint:

> Baby seal grows to be strong;    SEALs are designed to be strong;    seal should be made strong

Second hint:

> Baby seals can be cute;    Navy SEALs..well...depends;    seal, definitely not

Third hint:

> Seals are usually wet;    SEALs are wet when they're in water (duh);    seals are not

Final hint:

> Seal and sea-lion;    SEALS and USA;    seal is a magical tool for imprisoning someone.

Comment: to the third hint: sweating by workout was meant,  but your intepretation is also ok

Comment: Oh, missed it. Nice puzzle btw, really interesting format :D

Comment: there are more meanings in this word [soo many] (https://www.google.de/search?ei=DNOXW4aFJfLMrgTvnp2gDg&q=seal&oq=seal&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i67k1j0i131k1j0i67k1l4j0j0i67k1j0j0i67k1.3236.3752.0.5384.4.4.0.0.0.0.118.395.3j1.4.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.4.395...0i131i67k1.0.poScYw9TL_4)