# Teapot Riddle: my first is solid, my second is not touchable

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

If you don't know the rules of "teapot riddles", see [my first teapot riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/71953/teapot-riddle-no-1).
Make sure that the **word** for the first teapot is **the same** as for the second teapot.

First clue:

> My first teapot is solid.
>   My second teapot is not touchable.

Second clue:

> My first teapot represents the hopes of everybody.
>   My second teapot represents your own hopes.

Third clue:

> My first teapot gets chosen by the captain.
>   My second teapot gets chosen by yourself.

Final clue (makes the riddle very easy):

> The round one needs to go in the angular one.
>  Chase your second teapot until you reach it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess is:

> Goal (Soccer/footbal and a personal goal)

First Hint:

> Goal posts are solid.
> You can't touch a personal goal, per se

Second Hint:

> Your fans want you to score.
> A personal goal is your hope to "get somewhere" (sorry, poorly explained)

Third Hint:

> The captain, after the coin toss, picks the goal to defend (or attack).
> You chose your personal goals/dreams

Final Hint:

> The round ball goes in the rectangular goal.
> Chase your goals until you accomplish them!

Comment: Ahhh I was 30 seconds too late, nice work : )

Answer (score 4):

is it:

> goals

first part:

> goals can be tangible such as what is used on a soccer field but also abstract like dreams

second part:

> everyone has goals?

third part:

> You can choose your own goals but the captain of a team will choose what the team is going for

Comment: Good thinking! :-)

Answer (score 2):

First teapot

> order.

Second teapot is

> desire(s) / dream(s)

Comment: cool you tried and signed up ;) you almost have it

Answer (score 1):

I am quite sure about your second teapot.. not sure about your first teapot. It is:

> Dream(ambition, aspiration ) - not touchable, represents your hopes, people chase it

Edit:

> I think the first teapot matches with Vision from marvel, by the mention of  Captain. Also Vision is a synonym to Dream your second teapot

Comment: it is kind of ... almost  | and make sure that the word of teapot 1 is the same as the word of teapot 2