# Teapot Riddle: I'm two nouns and a verb

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

I want to thank Jannis for his [teapot riddles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/71953/5373) with this.

I am one word, but have 2 or more different meanings.

> I’m two nouns and a verb,
>
> Take my first, flip it around, you’ll get my last,
> You could find anywhere, in tubes and pipes,
> It’ll be quite a long time, for half of my life,
>
> Follow me, I’ll show you the way to another place,
> I’ll keep your dogs, cats, bunnies in line,
> While I help detectives solve a crime
>
> Connecting the dots, but more than that,
> Bringing your cable to your tv,
> Transporting power, that stuff’s easy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you

> LEAD?

Take my first, flip it around, you’ll get my last,

> If you flip an L you kind of get a D; also switching them makes DEAL

You could find anywhere, in tubes and pipes,

> Lead pipes

It’ll be quite a long time, for half of my life,

> Lead pipes have a long life (but eventually leech!)

Follow me, I’ll show you the way to another place,

> I can lead you somewhere

I’ll keep your dogs, cats, bunnies in line,

> Pet leads/leashes

While I help detectives solve a crime

> Following a lead

Connecting the dots, but more than that,

> Leading from step to step

Bringing your cable to your tv,

> Lead cable

Transporting power, that stuff’s easy

> Lead power generation

The last two lines could also refer to

> Electronics leads, destined to connect two locations electrically

Comment: Wow El-Guest you are the best at riddles! I hope you get to 10K quickly!

Comment: You’re welcome :D