# Teapot Riddle no.11 (fan made)

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, poetry

Teapot Riddle no.11 (fan made).

> > **Rules:**
>
> *I have **one word** which has **several** (2 or more) **meanings**.
>
> Each of the meanings is a teapot (first, second ...).
>
> You try to figure out the word with my Hints.*

- **First Hint:**

  > My first teapot flies, and my second will lift. 
  >  They take to the skies, but one can be a gift.
- **Second Hint:**

  > My first teapot smiles with no teeth to show. 
  >  My second lifts piles from wood to cargo.
- **Third Hint:**

  > My first teapot's young, with some paper to fold. 
  >  My second has swung, if too heavy to hold.
- **Final Hint (to make it easy):**

  > My third teapot stretches perhaps to see clear, 
  >  But you could use glasses, or might instead peer.

Good luck and have fun!
[Last riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72387/teapot-riddle-no-10?noredirect=1&lq=1), of which I was inspired by to make this one. Big thanks to @[Jannis](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/52327/jannis) for making them!

[Here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72372/teapot-riddle-no-9) is the teapot riddle before the last one if you have not seen it! 
 [Here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72096/teapot-riddle-4-fan-made?rq=1) is another fan-made teapot riddle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is it a

> crane

My first teapot flies, and my second will lift. 
They take to the skies, but one can be a gift.

> the bird flies, the machine lifts

My first teapot smiles with no teeth to show. 
My second lifts piles from wood to cargo.

> the bird has no teeth, the machine lifts piles

My first teapot's young, with some paper to fold. 
My second has swung, if too heavy to hold.

> origami crane, the machine can swing around

My third teapot stretches perhaps to see clear, 
But you could use glasses, or might instead peer.

> you can crane your neck

Comment: Yes, you got it! $(+1)$ Too easy? :D

Comment: The rot13(sbyqrq cncre) made me think of it.  the final hint threw me though till I noticed!  Nice!

Comment: I couldn't say much about the second teapot apart from the lifting, so I am glad you got it. When would you like the tick?

Comment: Whenever is fine, no hurry, give others a chance to enjoy it!

Comment: Well, congratulations! $\color{green}{\checkmark}$