# Teapot Riddle no.23 (fan made)

Tags: riddle, acrostic

> Rules: I have one word which has several (2 or more) meanings. Each of
>   the meanings is a teapot (first, second ...). You try to figure out
>   the word with the conversation between the teapots

**Hint 1:**

> First teapot: Humans are annoyed of my existence
>   Second teapot: Probably yeah, they are shocked even if they get a hint of my existence

**Hint 2:**

> First teapot: Humans hate me. Do they hate you as well?
>   Second teapot: Eventually they hate me too, but it has always been complicated

**Hint 3:**

> First teapot: I remind them of their mistakes
>   Second teapot: So you help them to rectify? I remind them of what they spoke

**Hint 4:**

> First teapot: Yeah, I am useless if I don't show up
>   Second teapot: Totally agree.. But I am useless if I do

Comment: Hope you all like it.

Comment: Open to edits and suggestions for improvement

Comment: Are you sure about the acrostic tag?

Comment: Yeah.. Not sure if placed it correctly..

Comment: I changed the title to maintain the series, hope you don't mind.

Comment: Not at all.. Thank you so much.. Sorry I couldn't add links to the previous riddles..

Comment: Can somebody please explain what we are supposed to do?

Comment: @KarisYuen we are trying to find one word with at least two different meanings: one meaning that matches the "first teapot" and the other that matches the "second teapot". For example, look at the [first](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/71953/teapot-riddle-no-1) teapot riddle or the one [before](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72761/teapot-riddle-no-22-fan-made) this (the latter being fan-made, actually). That way, you might get a better understanding of these so-called, "Teapot Riddles" :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Bug

In particular

> **First teapot** - bug, error in computer program or system 
>  **Second teapot** - bug, a concealed miniature microphone

First teapot: Humans are annoyed of my existence

> Computer bugs are a sign of something going wrong in a program.

Second teapot: Probably yeah, they are shocked even if they get a hint of my existence

> Anybody would be shocked to find out they are being bugged.

First teapot: Humans hate me. Do they hate you as well?

> I always hate when my code hits a bug, but they can be very serious.

Second teapot: Eventually they hate me too, but it has always been complicated

> There is a complicated balance always at play between personal privacy and state security.

First teapot: I remind them of their mistakes

> Computer bugs are the result of human error.

Second teapot: So you help them to rectify? I remind them of what they spoke

> Surveillance bugs record conversations.

First teapot: Yeah, I am useless if I don't show up

> Bugs are important to spot to make your code better.

Second teapot: Totally agree.. But I am useless if I do

> If you find a surveillance bug, who knows what has been recorded.

Acrostic

> The first letters of the second teapot's sentences spell **PEST** - a synonym for bug.

Comment: That is absolutely correct! :)