# Have Some Tea, people!

Tags: riddle, word, no-computers

Haven't been online for so long due to school and stuff :P
Saw a [teapot riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72791/teapot-riddle-no-23-fan-made#comment217874_72791) a while ago so here's one

> Teapot 1: What's with you and your slimy things?
>   Teapot 2: I help maintain the ecosystem! What about you, only existing in the minds of others?
>
> Teapot 1: Hey! I exist in books, magazines, everywhere! I'm so big, more than most can perceive!
>   Teapot 2: But you're usually used for things I can't even see!
>
> Teapot 1: At least I stay the same all the time, unlike you, moving around and being so disgusting!

Day 2 (one more clue)

> Teapot 3: How are you doing?
> Teapot 1: You aren't supposed to be here!
> Teapot 3: You just knew? Hah!
> Teapot 2: How much did you find out!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inspired by "Day 2" clue:

Teapot 1: What's with you and your slimy things?
Teapot 2: I help maintain the ecosystem! What about you, only existing in the minds of others?

> I am a mole (mole 1). And I can [benefit soil fertility by aerating and tilling it, and consume animals themselves considered pests](http://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/Mole_(animal)). But, you are more of an abstract concept (we will shortly see why).

Teapot 1: Hey! I exist in books, magazines, everywhere! I'm so big, more than most can perceive!

> I am a mole too (mole 2, pun unintended)!
>  I am [the amount of a chemical substance that contains  exactly 6.02214076×1023 constitutive particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mole_(unit)).
>  All matter is ultimately made up of atoms.
>  That 1023 is actually 10 raised to 23, which is *huge* by any earthly standard.

Teapot 2: But you're usually used for things I can't even see!

> Perhaps usage of mole 2 is beyond the comprehension of mole 1 (who we don't expect to be well, well educated).

Teapot 1: At least I stay the same all the time, unlike you, moving around and being so disgusting!

> Mole 2 is actually a representation of a universal constant (Avogadro constant). Mole 1 moves around and is *considered* a pest.

Day 2 (one more clue)

> Teapot 3: How are you doing?
>  Teapot 1: You aren't supposed to be here!
>  Thus said Mole 2 to Mole 3 who is a *spy*.
>  Teapot 3: You just knew? Hah!
>  Teapot 2: How much did you find out!?
>  A question which mole 3 would not prefer to answer as mole 1 is apparently not the boss or even on the same team! [just so that there's no confusion: Teapot 2 is mole 1 (animal), teapot 1 is mole 2 (constant) & teapot 3 is mole 3(spy)].

Comment: Nice! I forgot to give the day 3 clue but yeah

Answer (score 4):

Teapot 1: What's with you and your slimy things?
Teapot 2: I help maintain the ecosystem! What about you, only existing in the minds of others?

> I am a worm (short for earthworm).  And yeah, I am slimy, and it is well-known how I help maintain the ecosystem.

Teapot 1: Hey! I exist in books, magazines, everywhere! I'm so big, more than most can perceive!

> I am a [worm](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/worm) too. [COMPUTING]
>  a self-replicating program able to propagate itself across a network, typically having a detrimental effect.
>  Perhaps the allusion to books, magazines, everywhere pertains to (entities in) *cyberspace*.

Teapot 2: But you're usually used for things I can't even see!

> The activity of a [computer] worm cannot be *seen* by an earthworm.

Teapot 1: At least I stay the same all the time, unlike you, moving around and being so disgusting!

> Typically, a computer worm *replicates* itself and so it stays the same, even in a copy, in that sense. The earthworm moves around with its slimy body and is *considered* disgusting.

Comment: Check the tags but that's cool I didn't know worms exist in the cyberspace! But hey you're close! :)